# How to get the contents of a file from an eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am creating a plugin for eclipse and would like to know how can I get the contents of a specific file?

Example: a function that when passing a name, path or any identifier of the file returns the contents of it.

I've seen that the Ifile interface exists but I did not understand how to return the contents of a particular file from a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have IFile instances, just call the IFile.getContent() method to get an InputStream.

Comment: I have an IContainer that is an instance of IFile. but as IFile and a more specialized class the class IContainer does not have the method getContent ()

Comment: A resource can't be both a container and a file. http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html#getType-- . Ask it which it is and then cast to the right interface.

Comment: else if (member instanceof IFile && member.isDerived())
        {
        System.out.println(member);                                                                   
I am using this to get instances of IContainer which are also instances of IFiles. but I can not get their content